# PYTHON HERENCIA

Tags: python-3.x, poo

Alguien sabe porque se me sale el siguiente error "Moto() takes no arguments", entiendo que algo tiene que ver con la herencia porque la clase Moto no esta heredando de MetodosTransporte los parámetros del constructor pero no veo el error.

```
class MetodosTransporte():
    def __int__(self,marca,modelo):
        self.marca=marca
        self.modelo=modelo
        self.enMarcha=False
        self.acelera=False
        self.frena=False

    def arrancar(self):
        self.enMarcha=True

    def acelerar(self):
        self.acelera=True

    def frenar(self):
        self.frena=True

    def estado(self):
        print(f'MARCA: {self.marca} \nModelo:  {self.modelo} \nen Marcha:  {self.enMarcha} \nacelerando:  {self.acelera} \nfrenando:  {self.frena}')

class Moto(MetodosTransporte):#Esto quiere decir que la clase moto va a heredar de vehiculos
    pass

miMoto = Moto("HONDA", "CBR")# Este es el un objeto de la clase moto que heredo de la clase vehiculos

miMoto.estado()
```

Comment: Porque en`MetodosTransporte` has escrito `__int__()` por error. Así que esa clase no tiene método `__init__()` y solo tiene el constructor por defecto que le pone Python y que no admite parámetros.

Answer (score 0):

Dos errores:

```
class MetodosTransporte():
    def __int__(self, marca, modelo):
```

te faltó la "i" de "**init**"

Segundo, en Moto tienes que recibir los argumentos y pasarlos a la clase base usando `super().__init__()`.

La subclase Moto podría tener parámetros distintos a la clase base, por lo que debes recibirlos explícitamente y llamar al método `__init__` de la clase base con los parámetros que necesita.

El método `super()` te permite obtener la clase base (sin importar cual sea).

Solución:

```
class MetodosTransporte():
    def __init__(self, marca, modelo):
        self.marca=marca
...
class Moto(MetodosTransporte):#
    def __init__(self, marca, modelo):
        super().__init__(marca, modelo)

miMoto = Moto("HONDA", "CBR")  

miMoto.estado()
```

produce:

```
MARCA: HONDA 
Modelo:  CBR 
en Marcha:  False 
acelerando:  False 
frenando:  False

Process finished with exit code 0
```